# Best way to linking different entities to a single table

Tags: database-design, subtypes

I'm running for office and have created a web app for tracking my door knocks to voters at their homes. The database contains a table called `voters` that contains all the necessary information about voters in my community. I'm using mysql.

I'd like to add a new feature to track donors to my campaign. Not all of these donors live in the community and do not vote in the district where I'm running for office. I do not need to track the same kind of info for these individuals as I do for the voters so I'm going to place these individuals into a table called `nonvoters.`

Now, the individuals in my `voters` table can also make donations, and I want to track those as well.

Finally, I'd also like to track donations from organizations, so I also need an `organizations` table for storing information about the organizations.

To track the donations from both voters, nonvoters and organizations, I want to set up a new table called `donations.` This table would contain the appropriate details about each donation.

But I'm uncertain as to what the best structure is for linking the `donations` table to the `voters`, `nonvoters`, and `organizations` table should be. If I create a column called `donor_id` in the table to key it to the donors information, there's no way to know which table that ID refers to. So do I set up three columns, `nonvoter_id`, `voter_id` and `org_id` and insert the ID into the applicable column depending on whether the donor is a voter? This seems weird.

Or maybe I create a new column in each of the three tables called `donor_id` that I can use to link my data to the donations table. If I went this route, it seems like I'd have to do a some behind the scenes work to ensure the donor_id was unique and was keyed to the data inside the donations table.

Or maybe there are other approaches I'm not familiar with. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: RDBMS is not particularly good at this problem, largely because enhancing a single data model designed to do a specific thing ( track door knocks ) to suddenly do a completely separate thing as well ( track donations ) is not always easy.  For your purposes, I'd probably suggest option #2 from the OP of this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42434/database-design-two-1-to-many-relationships-to-the-same-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, you have provided a quite engaging context and analysis.

According to my understanding of your scenario description, some important aspects can be handled by means of **(Super)Type-Subtype relationships**. In this regard, [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92065/help-with-a-scenario-of-music-groups-and-members-in-erd-design/102069#102069) provides relevant information.

## Assumed business rules

As per your current specifications, the following assertions appear valid:

- A `Party`<sup>**[1]**</sup> is **either** a `Person` **or** an `Organization`.
- A `Party` grants **zero-one-or-many** `Donations`.
- A `Person` can be a `Voter` and a `NonVoter`.

## Preliminary logical data model

Therefore, I have derived the IDEF1X<sup>**[2]**</sup> logical data model presented in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjlB8.png).

[image: Fig. 1. Voting and Donations Preliminary Data Model]

**Party and Donation**

As you can see, the incorporation of the `Party` entity as an **exclusive supertype** provides the possibility for a `Person` or an `Organization` to be able to grant `Donations`, since the `PartyId` attribute **migrates**<sup>**[3]**</sup> from `Party` to `Donation`, but I have assigned a **role name**<sup>**[4]**</sup> (i.e., `DonorId`) to such attribute in order to make it more meaningful in the context of the `Donation` entity.

**Person and Organization**

In the same way, `PartyId` migrates to `Person` as `PersonId`, and to `Organization` as `OrganizationId`, and these two entities, in turn, can hold their specific attributes.

**Voter and NonVoter**

I consider that, in your business context, a given `Person` can be a `Voter` and a `NonVoter` over time, depending on the particular `District` in which said `Person` is located, thus I have **temporarily** depicted this circumstances in a **nonexclusive supertype** cluster, but **I consider that we need to clarify some points in this respect**.

## Aspects that require clarification

The goal of this data modeling excersise is to capture the things of interest with respect to your business context requirements, and one can serve that purpose by determining the **entities** involved along with their respective **attributes** (including, with especial attention, the ones that **uniquely identify** each entity ocurrence) and the way in which such entities are **interconected**. In this manner, the **semantic value** that said aspects hold for you, and your data users, is **paramount**. The better these factors are comprehended, the better they can be **depicted** in a data model.

Having said that, I have created three more models (**also preliminary**) in order to have a vehicule to exemplify some ideas about your scenario. [They are contained in this PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fzljygd9sem0ig/Elections%20Preliminary%20Data%20Models%20-%20Options%20for%20Enhancement.pdf), which you can download from Dropbox.

Then, here are the **concrete aspects** that need clarification:

1. How do you plan to inscribe people in your system? **(a)** Do you have access to the electoral register (or electoral roll)? **(b)** Will you enter this data once you have door knocked their house?
2. Which attributes do you want to store about a given `DoorKnock`?
3. It seems reasonable to state that a `Person` may receive the *status* of `Voter` or `NonVoter` in the context of —as mentioned above— **(a)** the `District` in which such `Person` resides **and (b)** a determined `Election` instance. What do you think about it?

   - *Maybe, a **person** must live within a certain **period** in a given **district** in order to be able to **vote** in a determined **election**.*
4. What are the attributes of interest in relation to a `Person`?
5. Which are the particular attributes that you want to retain regarding a `Voter`?
6. What are the specific attributes that you wish to store about a `NonVoter`?

   - *Perhaps, they are **personal attributes** that belong in the `Person` entity.*
7. It also appears fair to say that a `Donation` can be **granted** only in the context of an `Election` occurrence, is this correct?

   - *This possibility is expressed in all the three models.*
8. With respect to `Donations` granted by `Organizations`, **(a)** are organizations that *reside* outside your election district allowed to make donations, or **(b)** is this only permitted for organizations *located* in your specific district?

   - *If this is allowed only to local `Organizations`, it would be necessary to move the `District` PK from `Person` to `Party`. I am thinking that, actually, that **could be** the right place for this attribute, but let me know your ideas about it. I have illustrated this option in **Model C***.
9. How much `Donations` are allowed by each `Party`? **(a)** One, **(b)**  a fixed number, or **(c)** an undefined quantity?

   - *Option **(c)** is also currently presented in the three models*.
10. Are there restrictions related to **(a)** a `MinimumAmount` and **(b)** a `MaximumAmount` per individual `Donation`?
11. Do you have restrictions associated to **(a)** a `MinimumAmount` and **(b)** a `MaximumAmount` per the **total set** of `Donations` granted by a certain `Party`?
12. How do you identify an `Election` instance?

    - *I think that a given election can be uniquely identified by means of the **date** in which it is celebrated (as depicted in **Model A**) and, perhaps, by a **combination** of the **date** and the **district** where it is held (as depicted in **Model B**)*.
13. What attribute (or group or attributes) uniquely identify a `District` occurrence?

    - *As you know, I have used `DistrictNumber` for this purpose in all the models, but it may well be a different attribute.*

## Response to your comments

> I have never heard of type-subtype relationships in a database. This is very interesting.

Yes —as far as I know— **Type-Subtype** relationships were introduced, as such, in the **relational paradigm** back in 1979<sup>**[5]**</sup> and, unfortunately, they are not widely used in common implementations. But now that we know them, we can take advantage of this **interesting and powerful** structure in your scenario.

> I am not all that practiced with databases so not sure how to begin implementing the columns needed. All of my `INSERTS` are straightforward single table inserts and it looks like this approach will require some fancier queries. I'm definitely willing to learn, though.

Do not worry, it is completely understandable that you are familiar with other computer science branches but not that much with relational databases, and I consider that this is a good oportunity for you to know more about this fascinating discipline, **we all** learn new things every day.

Yes, INSERTing a row (or set of rows) in a database table implies different considerations than, say, creating a record or file in a programming language.

We need first to focus in obtaining a **stable** logical data model, then we will easily derive a physical model (DDL statements or “CREATE Table code”). Once we have a clear target (all the aforementioned) defined, I will be glad to offer some ideas and guidance in relation to your INSERTs implementation and other pertaining elements.

---

## Notes

<sub>1. **Party** is a term used in legal contexts to refer to a **single person** or **group of persons** that compose an **individual entity**.</sub>

<sub>2. Integration Definition for Information Modeling (**[IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)**) is a **highly recommendable** data modeling technique that was defined as a **standard** in december 1993 by the United States National Institute of Standards and Technology (**NIST**).</sub>

<sub>3. IDEF1X defines **key migration** as “The modeling process of placing the primary key of a parent or generic entity (*or supertype*) in its child or category entity (*or subtype*) as a foreign key”.</sub>

<sub>4. The use of **role names** is recommended since 1970 by [**Dr. E. F. Codd**](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm) in his seminal paper entitled **[“A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks”](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685)**. For its part, IDEF1X —keeping fidelity regards **relational** practices— also advocates role naming.</sub>

<sub>5. By **Dr. Codd** (as one would expect) in his work entitled **[“Extending the Database Relational Model to Capture More Meaning”](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320109)**.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Great question!  Here is an approach using super/sub-typing in the [barker-ellis notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barker%27s_notation) style.  In this approach super and sub-types are used only for classifying based upon a single, un-changing, fundamental characteristic possessed by all the entities of a given entity type.  This is similar to the [taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy) of biological organisms.  Using this style, we only sub-type based on who you **are**, not on the **role** you play.

[image]

In this example, we identify a party which can either be a person or an organization.  This is based on a single, fundamental, unchanging characteristic - if the entity is a single individual or a group of individuals.  A person can make a donation.  An organization can make a donation.  A person can vote.  An organization can **never** vote.  These things never change.

With respect to voting, it may seem to make sense to sub-type the **Person** based on if they are a voter or non voter.  But being a voter or a non voter has **nothing whatever** to do with who the person **is**.  Instead, it has everything to do with the district in which they **live**.  Therefore, we model a district entity type which may be **the home of** one or more persons.  Likewise, a person must be **residing in** one and only one district.

This approach solves the need to know who have made donations and the need to know who is and who is not a voter via naturally occurring information - where the person resides - instead of information we invented by declaring them a voter or a non voter - or both.  With respect to a person being **both** a voter or non-voter, that is mis-leading.  They could be both **over** time, but could never be both at a **moment in** time.  Therefore you must decide if you care about the history of their residence or not.  If you do, then you would instead create an entity type - say residence - to associate the person to the district in which they reside for the period of time they resided there.  I suspect you don't care however, and thus you would simply update the person's information to show their new district.  Either way, the approach is more intuitive than using sub-typing.  This is why I prefer the barker-ellis approach of limiting super and sub-typing to only fundamental classifications.

## Handling Missing Information

One thing does remain however where specialization makes sense.  You say you have additional information to store about a person if they live in your district and can thus vote for or against you.  In the approach I have given that information would be characteristics of a person regardless of where they live.  You are just choosing not to **collect** it if they don't live in your district, and to collect it if they do.  Therefore, for persons not living in your district, this information will be **missing**.

There are two approaches to this.  First, you could simply include those attributes for the person and leave them missing.  In mySQL you would make the columns NULLABLE.  That approach is simple, but if you **ever** want to write a query where you use one of those attributes as a predicate you now have to deal with the complexities of [three value logic (3VL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), and the fact that SQL does not implement its 3VL consistently.  If instead you want to avoid 3VL, you can use specialization to create an additional entity type to hold the extra information only when it is known.  A row is placed there only for those persons for whom you've collected the data.  Now this doesn't avoid NULLs altogether as you must deal with outer joins, but you **can** avoid nulls if you chose to via **[coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)**.

## Naming the Specialization

I would **not** call the new specialization entity type **voter**.  It is pure coincidence that at this moment you aren't collecting the additional information because you only need that information for persons living in your district who can vote for you.  What if in the future you **do** want to collect that information for other reasons?  What if you happen to know that information anyway for someone who doesn't live in your district and don't want to just toss it away?  What will you do if someone for whom you have collected the information moves out of your district?  Do you want to **delete** that good information you collected?  If you do, what if they move back?  You will have to collect it again!

Instead, I would call the table something slightly different like **voter profile**.  This denotes the information pertains to the person as a voter, and that information absolutely describes additional things about them **regardless** of whether or not they live in your district.

## Conclusion

I hope this approach gives you some additional food for though.  To learn more about the barker-ellis approach to business modeling you can check out [David Hay](http://www.essentialstrategies.com)'s [Enterprise Model Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935504053), and also Richard Barker's [CASE*Method Entity Relationship Modelling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201416964).  With respect to missing information, I would recommend you check out Fabian Pascal's paper "The Final Null in the Coffin," part of his excellent [Practical Database Foundation Series](http://www.dbdebunk.com/p/papers_3.html), and also Date and Darwen's [The Third Manifesto](http://www.thethirdmanifesto.com) site where they have some great resources on various approaches to handling missing information without nulls.