# Foreign keys pointing to "look-up" tables: Should we reference Id or Code values?

Tags: database-design, application-design

We are rewriting from a huge monolithic application to smaller application using rest.

While the old application had one huge tables called REFERENCE tables with applicable values had all these `ids` and `codes` and `names` and `description`. The other tables had references using `id`s. 
E.g Current Design

### Tbl_Status_Types

```
 +---------------+----------------+---------+
 | id            | code           |  name   |
 +---------------+----------------+---------+
 |             1 |              O | Open    |
 |             2 |              C | Close   |
 +---------------+----------------+---------+
```

### Tbl_Order

```
     +---------------+----------------+---------+
     | order_id      | cust_id        |fk_status|
     +---------------+----------------+---------+
     |             1 |              O | O or 1  |
     |             2 |              C | C or 2  |
     +---------------+----------------+---------+
```

### Question:

- Should the Foreign Key FK_Status be referencing `ID` or `CODE`
- what value adding a `CODE` would add to other than readability and is it maintainable?
- if you are exposing your rest endpoint for an operation to update status - which value would you expose `name` or `code`

Comment: You may find of help several deliberations contained in [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158878/63644).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best practices regarding lookup tables in relational databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142825/what-are-the-best-practices-regarding-lookup-tables-in-relational-databases)