# Design with inheritance and two 1 to many relationships to the same table

Tags: database-design

**Quick schema overview:**
Below is a schema being a subject of my question. In the design there are two "regular" tables `questions` and `notes` as well as two "abstract" tables:

- `elements`, with "concrete" implementations:

  - `video_clips`, `podcasts`, `books`, `articles`
- `markers` with following "implementations":

  - `book_pages`, `article_pages` and `time_frames`

**What I would like to achieve:**
I would like to be able to put a note or a question in an element. But along with the information that let me find it quicker, thus f.e. if book was my element, I would use a page marker (`book_page`). If podcast was my element I would use a minute marker (`time_frame`). 

To give an example: Let's say I have:

- a book `B1` with `100` pages
- a book `B2` with `200` pages
- a podcast `P1` that lasts `8` minutes

Now I want to be able to put a note for page number `21` for the book `B1` saying: `Unlike many other metals, iron does not form amalgams with mercury.` - f.e. because that statement drew my attention while reading the book and I want to highlight that by putting a note with that sentence, and connect it to `B1` p. `21`. 

Let's say in podcast `P1` in minute `4` I heard a sentence: `Bank A has better mortgage plan than bank B because X Y Z`. I want to be able to put a question related to `P1` and minute `4` saying: `Why X is better in bank A and not C?`

**Problems:**
There are two important topics related to that design:

1. Inheritance
2. [Two 1 to many relationships to the same table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42434/database-design-two-1-to-many-relationships-to-the-same-table)

I could get rid of the `markers` table, and relate `book_pages` with `books`, `article_pages` with `articles` and `time_frames` with both `podcasts` and `video_clips`. The problem is that I would have two FK in `time_frames` (let's assume it's acceptable with `CHECK` constraint) and three foreign keys in both `notes` and `questions` (`book_page_id`,`article_page_id`,`time_frame_id`) - and that is unacceptable. I've introduced `markers` table to solve that issue and have only one FK in `notes` and `questions`. Unfortunately that comes with high price, because now querying for an element needs twice more joins (for `elements` and `markers`).

I am not looking for the perfect solution because giving the problems there isn't one, I know I need to adopt the compromise but the question is **if my compromise/design is acceptable or not** ?

[image: user created schema being a subject of the present question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can (and should) simplify this. Class inheritance doesn't make as much sense in SQL (DDL) as it does in OO programming languages. Instead, you should follow normalization rules.

I'd suggest a solution like this:

```
CREATE TABLE media (
  media_id int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
  media_type enum('book', 'article', 'podcast', 'video') NOT NULL
  -- Other media columns here
  -- If you need a few columns specific to one media_type, that's OK
);

CREATE TABLE media_comment (
  media_comment_id int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  media_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  comment_type enum('question', 'note') NOT NULL,
  marker int unsigned COMMENT 'unit: seconds for video/podcast, page for book/article',      
  comment_body TEXT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT media_comment_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES media(media_id)
);
```

This has the advantage of significantly simplifying your queries as well as being easier to read / understand.

If you need a few columns specific to certain media types, that's OK. These columns will then be `NULL` for the other media types. The overhead of `NULL` values is very small, though varies with database system / storage engine. See e.g. here for an explanation of the InnoDB storage engine in MariaDB and MySQL: [NULL in MySQL (Performance & Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063773/1996856)) (StackOverflow)

Comment: I was considering similar "generic" approach but wasn't sure about columns specific to one `media` in the same table but could you write something more why `If you need a few columns specific to one media_type, that's OK` ?

Comment: Hi @user3529850 I've added a little bit at the end re: overhead of unused columns, i.e. with value equal to NULL.

Comment: one more question, so looking through the prism of hibernate that's just a `single table` strategy right?

Comment: @user3529850 Afraid I don't have much experience with Hibernate. From a quick read, it sounds like you could be correct.