# Foreign Key Referencing ID of One of 2+ Other Tables

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

Given 3 tables — e.g. `posts`, `comments`, and `tags` — is there a way of having a foreign key in one of them referencing a primary key of *one* of the other two?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        CONSTRAINT posts_pk PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        CONSTRAINT comments_pk PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        CONSTRAINT tags_pk PRIMARY KEY
);

DROP TYPE IF EXISTS s_type;
CREATE TYPE s_type AS ENUM (
    'POST',
    'COMMENT'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag_mentions (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        CONSTRAINT tag_mentions_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    source_type s_type NOT NULL,
    source_id UUID NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT tag_mention_id_fk
            -- Is something like this possible?
            REFERENCES posts (id) OR comments (id)
);
```

Maybe there's a way of doing this with a composite index between `s_type` and `posts` and `comments` IDs?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42434, https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/92065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a notoriously hard problem in SQL, and there is no entirely satisfying solution. You will find many similar questions such as [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113122/conditional-foreign-key-relationship).

The best, or least bad, solution depends on the concrete use case. Here are some of the classical approaches:

1. create two foreign key column in `tag_mentions` and use a check constraint that makes sure that only one of them is `NOT NULL` and that it matches the `source_type` setting

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tag_mentions
      ADD posts_id uuid REFERENCES posts,
      ADD comments_id uuid REFERENCES comments,
      ADD CHECK (
             (source_type = 'POST' AND
              posts_id IS NOT NULL AND
              comments_id IS NULL)::integer +
             (source_type = 'COMMENT' AND
              posts_id IS NULL AND
              comments_id IS NOT NULL)::integer
             = 1
          );
   ```
2. instead of two tables, create a single table `posts_comments` that contains the columns from both entities and a `type` column, then reference this table with the foreign key
3. have the foreign keys point in the other direction, from `posts` and `comments` to `tag_mentions`

The third solution has the disadvantage that you cannot prevent both a `posts` and `comments` entry from being related to a single `tag_mentions`.

The choice between 1. and 2. usually depends on your concrete situation: if `posts` and `comments` are very similar, 2. is appealing. Also, if there are not two categories (`posts` and `comments`), but way more, 2. is probably the better solution. Otherwise, 1. may be the way to go.

---

### Useful References

- [Conditional Foreign Key Relationship](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114281/166587)
- [Modeling a scenario in which each Music Artist is either a Group or a Solo Performer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/92065/166587)
- [Database design: Two 1 to many relationships to the same table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42434/166587)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But could you please give me a code example as to how to achieve item 1 in your suggestions? It's the only one I don't think is that trivial.

Comment: Also, one other thing since you seem far more knowledgeable on SQL than I am: do you have recommendations of books or other references for these common SQL design problems? My knowledge on SQL is probably 100% web-search-based, but I feel like so many problems I have should be in a good SQL design book somewhere...

Comment: I have no reference to literature; this is just what I think and what I picked up along the way.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept the answer, but could you still add code to item 1?